# Invalid form body when attempting to push slash commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have looked far and wide for answers to my question and have yet to find anything that helped me, I try to push my slash commands globally and they do not work as in discord shoots back with this when I execute the code:

```bash
Started refreshing 13 application (/) commands.
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
1.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
2.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
3.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
4.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
5.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
6.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
7.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
8.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
9.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
10.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
11.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
12.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/ayden/microwave.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:753:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/ayden/microwave.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:565:14)
    at async REST.request (/home/ayden/microwave.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:999:22)
    at async /home/ayden/microwave.js/deploy.js:25:16 {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object]
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/867964961417203743/commands',
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: [
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined,
      undefined
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the code from the deploy.js file:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(JSON.stringify(command.data));
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

If you could help me solve this that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you also share your command structure (slash command builder)

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean so I will refer you to the github page

https://github.com/microwave-inc/microwave.js

Comment: Can you post your slahcommands js file as well. Because the error is in one of them.

Comment: The only uncommited file is deploy.js which I have provided here, everything else is within the github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to push `command.data` to the `commands` array.

Looking at one of your command files, I noticed that that property doesn’t exist. Instead, the Slash Command Builder is located at `<command>.help.data` (e. g. in your about.js, you are using:

```
module.exports.help = {
    name: "about", 
    cat: "Info",
    description: "Get information about the bot",
    aliases: "",
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("about").setDescription("Get information about the bot"),
}
```

This module.exports points to the export property .help and has the property .data which contains the SlashCommandBuilder.

To solve this issue, just change the `deploy.js` line 11 to the following:

```js
commands.push(JSON.stringify(command.help.data));
```

This points to the correct location of the SlashCommandBuilder - preventing the array to just be filled with `undefined` because the property given doesn’t exist.

I hope this helps in resolving the problem.

Comment: I was able to figure this bit out myself, but now one of the values is coming back as undefined, specifically the "files" value, and I am getting the following error: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType

Comment: Do you mean the “commandFiles” variable? Also try logging the `commands` array, after you filled it to check where the error might be coming from.

Comment: I figured this out completely on my own a bit ago, All my files were .ts files instead of .js and sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your help as well!!!